# ECC Encryption and Decryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption

Can we encrypt large files with ECC or it is like RSA works for small only? can anyone please recommend a good website for ECC Java implementation.

Thanks

Comment: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong format: RAW bytes needed...I am getting this error when IO try to encrypt files with ECC with Sun provider. Can anyone know what is causing that error

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to set the classpath of the FlexiProvider to use it the ECC algorithm @ Artjom B.

Answer (score 7):

In general you are *required* to perform [hybrid encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) with ECC. ECIES for instance is basically a key agreement followed by symmetric encryption. So you cannot *directly* encrypt anything with ECIES, which is the most common ECC method for encryption. Basically you should couple it to a symmetric cipher. This is actually the best scheme for RSA encryption as well, most of the time.

---

As you can see you can use this directly as a `Cipher` using CBC mode & PKCS#7 padding, but beware of the large header (117 bytes for a 384 curve, no less). This is required to perform the key derivation. Make sure that the public key is *properly validated* (I'm not sure about the Bouncy Castle code in this regards, haven't taken a look at it).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    KeyPairGenerator ecKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    ecKeyGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("brainpoolP384r1"));

    // doesn't work, which means we are dancing on the leading edge :)
    // KeyPairGenerator ecKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    // ecKeyGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp384r1"));

    KeyPair ecKeyPair = ecKeyGen.generateKeyPair();
    System.out.println("What is slow?");

    Cipher iesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES");
    iesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ecKeyPair.getPublic());

    byte[] ciphertext = iesCipher.doFinal(com.google.common.base.Strings.repeat("owlstead", 1000).getBytes());

    iesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ecKeyPair.getPrivate());
    byte[] plaintext = iesCipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

    System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(ciphertext));
    System.out.println(new String(plaintext));
}
```

Comment: BUt what the implementatipon that Bouncy Castle provides for ECC, does it also use symmetric algorithm in it... also Is it possible to encrypt large files with it? @owlstead.. Thanks very much

Comment: For sure. In 1.51 it is using CBC encryption so that should be safe for confidentiality (**if** padding oracles are not possible). Be warned that previous versions [used ECB](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/ECC-with-ECIES-Encrypt-Decrypt-Questions-td4656750.html) which is not secure.

Comment: Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES") always throws below exception java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No such algorithm: ECIESwithAES

Comment: @Ranganatha When BC removed the ECB variant, they changed the algorithm identifiers. Try `ECIESwithAES-CBC`. See https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/commit/9385b0ebd277724b167fe1d1456e3c112112be1f

Comment: Hmm, must have missed that earlier comment. Interesting that they removed the previous ones instead of just adding new ones. Nowadays you should really be using an authenticated mode though, such as AES-GCM. I'll do some research on how to enable that - but I suspect you have to perform DH yourself instead of specifying ECIES. I'll try and update the answer later on.

Comment: I just run into a problem with ECIESwithAES and wanted to share my solution. I post an updated example below.

Answer (score 4):

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

```
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    
  KeyPairGenerator ecKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC",    BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
  ecKeyGen.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
    
  KeyPair ecKeyPair = ecKeyGen.generateKeyPair();
  System.out.println("What is slow?");

  // Bouncycastle has changed the api, we now need a nonce 
  // therfore a third parameter as a IESParamSpec is required

  /generate a nonce
  SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
  byte [] nonce = new byte[16];
  random.nextBytes(nonce);
  IESParameterSpec iesParamSpec = new IESParameterSpec(null, null, 256, 256, nonce, false);
    
  Cipher iesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES-CBC");
  Cipher iesDecipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIESwithAES-CBC");
  // enrypt message
  iesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, ecKeyPair.getPublic(),  iesParamSpec);
  String message = "Hello World";
  byte[] ciphertext = iesCipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
  System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(ciphertext));

  // decrypt encrypted text  
  iesDecipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ecKeyPair.getPrivate(),   iesCipher.getParameters());
  byte[] plaintext = iesDecipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
    
  System.out.println(new String(plaintext));
```

}

Comment: The above shown example works with BouncyCastle 1.66 - I haven't tried any other versions.

The main differences are
  - ECIESwithAES-CBC instead of just ECIESwithAES
  - you have to use two different ciphers for encrypting and decrypting
  - you have to initialize the cipher for decrypting with the parameters of the encryption cipher.

Comment: This works for me very well. You saved my times. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since BouncyCastle has made some changes after version 1.66 I have edited the code to reflect the new requirements